# How can I find the location of JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

This is the code:

```
 <div class="mmOtherOdds">
     <div class="odd t1 n1">
         <div>1</div>
         <div>
             <a id="h_w_PC_ctl11_repMM_ctl01_repOdds_ctl01_lnkOdds">3,29</a>
         </div>
     </div>

     <div class="odd t1 n13">
         <div>1</div>
         <div>
             <a href="javascript:AddCoupon(sCouponButtonClientID,sCouponQuotaClientID,3430082440);" id="h_w_PC_ctl11_repMM_ctl01_repOdds_ctl02_lnkOdds" class="down">2,22</a>
         </div>
     </div>
```

I need to know how I can find the location of this

```
 href="javascript:AddCoupon(sCouponButtonClientID,sCouponQuotaClientID,3430082440);"
```

Comment: What are you using to look at the code?

Comment: You target the element, for instance by ID, and then you get the attribute

Comment: **Hi**, please be more specific and do your research (Google!) before posting such a broad question on SO.

Comment: this the link of site : http://www.planet365all.ovh/
login : hassen383
pass: H5858
login and u can see the source code + idownload all the js files

Comment: @Mekano: You should post all relevant code in the question.  Once this question is solved (or if that link dies), then the question won't be useful to anyone.

Comment: Also what do you mean by "find the location"?  What exactly are you looking for?  What's your end-goal here?

Comment: my problem is 
i want to make a site like this www.planet365.ovh my problem is wen i load the code he don't load this is my site http://m3kano-001-site1.ctempurl.com/a.asp
use this to login in login : hassen383 pass: H5858 login

Comment: @Mekano: So, `planet365` is *not* your site, then?  Are you seeing any errors in your console?  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: i want to make a site like planet365.ovh
this my site www.m3kano-001-site1.ctempurl.com/a.asp
my problem is when i put the code in the case of BULLETIN the code didn't load 
you can try with this code ( HTY41 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the source code of your page. Most probably, you will find multiple `<script>` tags. One of these tags has a `src` attribute pointing to the JS file that contains `AddCoupon` function definition.

Unfortunately, I can't tell you more without having a context

**UPD**: There is no function called `AddCoupon` on the provided website. You can check it by opening a JavaScript console in any modern browser and click on one of these buttons:

[image]

You'll see something like this:

[image]

Comment: You should ask for "context" before posting an answer that may not help the OP.

Comment: login = hassen383 pass: H5858

Comment: what's the solution then !!

Comment: Errm... To write the function I guess?

Answer (score 0):

You can search for *AddCoupon* in the tool you're now using to view to web page's source code.

If you can't find it, then you'll have to go look into each of any *.js file loaded on the page (they're usually referenced in the head, but could be anywhere). They should be publicly accessible when you paste the url in your browser.

Comment: this is the site : planet365.ovh
login:hassen383
pass:H5858 u can see the source code + idownload all the js files